# C++ Windows - How to get process path from its PID (error)

Tags: c++, windows, process, path, psapi

I want to use pid to get the full path of the process.

```
#include <psapi.h>

HANDLE processHandle = NULL;
TCHAR filename[MAX_PATH];

processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, nPID);
if (processHandle != NULL) 
{
    if (GetModuleFileNameEx(processHandle, NULL, filename, MAX_PATH) == 0) 
    {
        //fail to get module file name
    } 
    else 
    {
        //module file name : filename
    }
    CloseHandle(processHandle);
} 
else 
{
    //fail to open process
}
```

This is the code that gets the path of the process using pid.

However, when I execute it, the following error occurs.

( I am using visual c ++ 6.0. )

```
Linking...
Process01Dlg.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _GetModuleFileNameExA@16
Debug/Process01.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
Error executing link.exe.
```

- QueryFullProcessImageName
- GetModuleFileName
- GetModuleFileNameEx
- GetProcessImageFileName

All of the above methods have caused an error.

Is this a problem with the version?

Please answer. Thank you :)

Comment: _"... I am using visual c ++ 6.0..."_ if you mean Visual Studio 6 than please update to a newer verson: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#6.0_(1998)   MSVC 2017 is free for personal/small business use.

Comment: I have reason to use that version...

Comment: Problem is all the online documentation and also my memory have been retired.  What do the docs than come with VC 6 say is the library required for that function?  The online MSDN docs only go back as far as Windows XP.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683198(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you forget to link your product with the `psapi.lib`. Add it to the project dependencies.

Not sure it would work in VC6.0.

However MSDN recommends other functions for retrieving process names:

> To retrieve the name of the main executable module for a remote process, use the **GetProcessImageFileName** or **QueryFullProcessImageName** function. This is more efficient and more reliable than calling the **GetModuleFileNameEx** function with a NULL module handle.

Comment: It was resolved by adding `#pragma comment (lib, "psapi.lib")` Thank you~

Comment: @areum, `QueryFullProcessImageName` should be used in Vista and later. It requires only limited access to the target process. Note that, as an unreliable implementation detail, I see that in Windows 10 `GetModuleFileNameEx` also only needs limited access when `hModule` is `NULL`. For this case it's implemented the same as `QueryFullProcessImageName`, by calling `NtQueryInformationProcess` to get the `ProcessImageFileNameWin32`.  Of course, you should assume that `GetModuleFileNameEx` needs full access to read virtual memory in the target process.